# Hi iam doing application migration from Websphere applcation server to Liberty while doing iam facing error

Tags: slf4j, apache-commons-logging

err] SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

[err] SLF4J: Found binding in [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/AF51548/Downloads/wlp-webProfile7-18.0.0.1%20(1)/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/112/data/cache/com.ibm.ws.app.manager_1/.cache/egiqt-ear-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/.cache/egiqt-war-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

[err] SLF4J: Found binding in [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/AF51548/Downloads/wlp-webProfile7-18.0.0.1%20(1)/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/112/data/cache/com.ibm.ws.app.manager_1/.cache/egiqt-ear-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/.cache/egiqt-war-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

[err] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

[ERROR   ] Critical error during deployment:

CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

```
   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:293)

   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2384)

   at [internal classes]
```

Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

```
   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:357)

   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:226)

   ... 2 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

```
   at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:504)

   at [internal classes]

   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

   at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.el.SpringBeanELResolver.<init>(SpringBeanELResolver.java:43)

   at org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver.<init>(SpringBeanFacesELResolver.java:68)

   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)

   at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:268)

   at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.addELResolver(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:575)

   at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:302)

   at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)

   at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116)

   at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)

   at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:216)

   at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:338)
```

this is my server.xml

```
<!-- Enable features -->

<featureManager>

    <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>

    <feature>commons-logging-1.1.1</feature>

   <feature>jsf-2.2</feature>

    <feature>cdi-1.2</feature>

    <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>

    <feature>managedBeans-1.0</feature>

    <feature>beanValidation-1.1</feature>

    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>

    <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>

     <feature>el-3.0</feature>



    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>

</featureManager>



<!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->

<httpEndpoint httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>





    <library id="db2JDBCDriverLibrary" name="DB2DriverLibrary">

    <fileset dir="C:/Program Files/IBM/SQLLIB/java" includes="db2jcc4.jar db2jcc_license_cu.jar"/>

</library>



<!-- DB2 driver -->

<jdbcDriver id="db2JDBCDriver" javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2ConnectionDataSource" javax.sql.DataSource="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2JccDataSource" javax.sql.XADataSource="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource" libraryRef="db2JDBCDriverLibrary"/>

<dataSource id="***_DataSource" jndiName="jdbc/****">

   <jdbcDriver libraryRef="db2JDBCDriverLibrary"/>

    <properties.db2.jcc beginTranForResultSetScrollingAPIs="false" beginTranForVendorAPIs="false" connectionSharing="1" databaseName="***" enableClientInformation="false" enableMultithreadedAccessDetection="false" errorDetectionModel="ExceptionMapping" freeResourcesOnClose="false" jmsOnePhaseOptimization="false" name="******" nonTransactionalDataSource="false" optimizeDB2ForGetUseClose="false" password="****" portNumber="****" reauthentication="false" retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage="true" serverName="****" traceLevel="-1" unbindClientRerouteListFromJndi="false" useTransactionRedirect="false" user="****" validateNewConnection="false"/>

    <connectionManager agedTimeout="600" connectionTimeout="10" maxIdleTime="600" maxPoolSize="10" minPoolSize="1" reapTime="180"/>

   </dataSource>
```

Here is my web.xml

```
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

   <display-name>

   egiqt-war</display-name>

   <context-param>

          <description>

          State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>

          <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>

          <param-value>client</param-value>

   </context-param>

   <context-param>

          <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>

          <param-value>resources.application</param-value>

   </context-param>

   <context-param>

          <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>

          <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>

   </context-param>

   <context-param>

          <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>

          <param-value>true</param-value>

   </context-param>



   <filter>

          <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>

          <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>

          <init-param>

                 <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>

                 <param-value>10240</param-value> <!-- 10 Mb -->

          </init-param>

   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>

          <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>

          <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

   </filter-mapping>



     <filter>

          <filter-name>UserAuthenticator</filter-name>

          <filter-class>org.UserAuthenticator</filter-class>

   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>

          <filter-name>UserAuthenticator</filter-name>

          <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

   </filter-mapping>   

   <context-param>

          <description>

          Comma-delimited list of context-relative resource paths under which the JSF implementation
```

will look for application configuration resources, before loading a configuration resource

named /WEB-INF/facesconfig.xml (if such a resource exists).

```
          <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>

          <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>

   </context-param>

   <!--<context-param>

          <description>

          The default suffix for extension-mapped resources that contain JSF components.
```

Default is '.jsp'.

```
          <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>

          <param-value>.jsp</param-value>

   </context-param>

   --><context-param>

          <description>

          Monitors Faces JSP files for modifications and synchronizes a running server with
```

the changes without restarting the server. If this parameter is set to false or

removed from the deployment descriptor, any changes made to Faces JSP files may

not be seen by the server until it is restarted. This parameter is usually set

to true while the Faces JSP files are being developed and debugged in order to

improve the performance of the development environment.

```
          <param-name>com.ibm.ws.jsf.JSP_UPDATE_CHECK</param-name>

          <param-value>true</param-value>

   </context-param>

   <!-- <context-param>

          <description>

          Load JSF runtime when the application server starts up. If this parameter is set to false or removed,
```

JSF runtime will be loaded and initialized when the first JSF request is processed.

This may disable custom JSF extensions, such as factories defined in the project.

```
          <param-name>com.ibm.ws.jsf.LOAD_FACES_CONFIG_AT_STARTUP</param-name>

          <param-value>true</param-value> -->

   </context-param>

   <listener>

          <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>

   </listener>

   <listener>

   <listener-class>org.backingbean.SessionListener

   </listener-class>

   </listener>





   <servlet>

          <servlet-name>Login Servlet</servlet-name>

          <jsp-file>pages/public/login.jsp</jsp-file>          

   </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>

          <servlet-name>Login Servlet</servlet-name>

             <url-pattern>/pages/public/Login.xhtml</url-pattern>

   </servlet-mapping> 



   <servlet>

          <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

          <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>

          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>

          <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

          <url-pattern>

          *.faces</url-pattern>

   </servlet-mapping>

   <servlet-mapping>

          <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

          <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>

   </servlet-mapping>

   <servlet-mapping>

          <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

          <url-pattern>

          *.jsf</url-pattern>

   </servlet-mapping>





   <context-param>

          <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>

          <param-value>true</param-value>

   </context-param>
```

```
  <!-- Session idle timeout in min. -->

  <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>

</session-config>
```

Please any body have any idea tell me

Comment: This error has **nothing** to do with spring, jsf or PrimeFaces. It is a plain slf4j/commonsLogging issue as the error states.

Comment: how to resolve this issue